# Bootstrap modal content not showing in Firefox or Safari, Phone aswell

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the following code to create a boostrap modal in Wordpress:

```
        <!-- slider -->
        <a id="osta" class="anchor"></a>
        <div id="slider-section" class="slider-section baas-slider">
        <div class="wide-grid gray-back">
            <div class="inner-grid">
            <div class="sliders">
            <?php if( have_rows('b-slider') ):
                    $counter2 = 1;
                    while ( have_rows('b-slider') ) : the_row(); ?>
                    <div class="b-slide">
                        <div class="button-baas">
                            <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#serviceModal<?php echo $counter2; ?>"><?php the_sub_field('b-price'); ?></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <?php endwhile; $counter2++; endif; ?>
            </div>
            </div><!-- wide-back -->
        </div><!-- slider section -->   

<!-- modal -->
<?php if( have_rows('modal') ):
    $counter3 = 1;
    while ( have_rows('modal') ) : the_row(); ?>
<div class="modal" id="serviceModal<?php echo $counter3; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="serviceModal<?php echo $counter3; ?>Label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="helper">
    <div class="modal-dialog wide-grid">
        <div class="modal-controls">
            <div class="btn-next">
                <span class="ion-chevron-right"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-prev">
                <span class="ion-chevron-left"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span class="ion-close"></span></button>
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body content-inner">
         <div class="flexing">
            <div  class="flex">
                <?php the_sub_field('modal-1'); ?>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endwhile; $counter3++; endif; ?>
<!-- modal -->
```

For some reason I only see the backdrop of the modal when I open it in Firefox, Safari, android or iOS. Chrome works fine. What could be causing this?

View site here: http://no11.ee/klienditugi/kliendibaas/#osta (click on the price button)

Comment: Maybe you should change the position of the backdrop in the HTML? Maybe put it just before the modal so they have the same parent?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by moving the modal to footer.php before the `</body>` tag. Page editing now under the 'Options' page with ACF.